# How to get SQL equivalent of cume_dist in pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I tried different pandas methods such as rank, qcut, quantile but was not able to get the SQL equivalent of `cume_dist()`. How to get the following result in pandas?

The complete question solved in SQL is found in this website: https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/ranking/4

## Setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['Molly', 'Ashes', 'Felix', 'Smudge', 'Tigger', 'Alfie', 'Oscar', 'Millie', 'Misty', 'Puss', 'Smokey', 'Charlie'],
          'breed': ['Persian', 'Persian', 'Persian', 'British Shorthair', 'British Shorthair', 'Siamese', 'Siamese', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'Maine Coon', 'British Shorthair'],
          'weight': [4.2, 4.5, 5.0, 4.9, 3.8, 5.5, 6.1, 5.4, 5.7, 5.1, 6.1, 4.8],
          'color': ['Black', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Black', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Tortoiseshell', 'Brown', 'Black'],
          'age': [1, 5, 2, 4, 2, 5, 1, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4]})
```

## SQL code for cume_dist

```sql
select name, weight, ntile(4) over ( order by weight) as weight_quartile from cats order by weight
```

## Required output (sql gives this, how to do in pandas?)

- SQL implementation given here: https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/ranking/4

```
name    weight  percent
Tigger  3.8 8
Molly   4.2 17
Ashes   4.5 25
Charlie 4.8 33
Smudge  4.9 42
Felix   5.0 50
Puss    5.1 58
Millie  5.4 67
Alfie   5.5 75
Misty   5.7 83
Oscar   6.1 100
Smokey  6.1 100
```

## Question: How to do this in Pandas?

Is there any way that we can use only numpy and pandas?

Comment: why you are not using spark-sql ? In case you are using Spark

Comment: @dsk This is not big data and I am not using Spark. Pandas have so many functions I am sure somehow this can be implemented using pandas.

Comment: okay - In that case if you really want to get a Pandas DF I will suggest you to get the calculation done in PySpark or Spark SQL and convert that Spark DF to a Pandas DF : # Spark to Pandas
df_pd = df.toPandas()

# Pandas to Spark
df_sp = spark_session.createDataFrame(df_pd)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python (PySpark) version:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

# Define two windows for cumulating weight
win = Window().orderBy('weight') # rolling sum window
win2 = Window().orderBy(F.lit(1)) # total sum window

# get cumulative distribution
df = df.withColumn('cume_dist', F.sum('weight').over(win)*100./F.sum('weight').over(win2))
```

Comment: This gives value 80 for third last entry Molly, however, it should be 83.

Comment: hmm ok weird I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

## create spark df

```
schema = StructType([
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('breed', StringType(), True),
    StructField('weight', DoubleType(), True),
    StructField('color', StringType(), True),
    StructField('age', IntegerType(), True),
])

sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df, schema)
sdf.createOrReplaceTempView("cats")
```

## use sql functions in spark df

```py
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import cume_dist

w = Window.orderBy(sdf['weight'])

sdf.select("weight", (cume_dist().over(w) * 100).cast(
    IntegerType()).alias("percentile")).show()
```

## output

```
+------+----------+
|weight|percentile|
+------+----------+
|   3.8|         8|
|   4.2|        16|
|   4.5|        25|
|   4.8|        33|
|   4.9|        41|
|   5.0|        50|
|   5.1|        58|
|   5.4|        66|
|   5.5|        75|
|   5.7|        83|
|   6.1|       100|
|   6.1|       100|
+------+----------+
```